# Update Oracle BLOB value in a batch

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, blob

I'm trying to update a series of BLOB values using the following code. Note how we're not using `Blob` objects, but just calling `setBytes`.

```
try (PreparedStatement p = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE table SET data = ? WHERE id = ?") {
    for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> d : updates.entrySet()) {
        p.setBytes(1, d.getValue());
        p.setString(2, d.getKey());
        p.addBatch();
    }

    p.executeBatch();
}
```

However, this is running really slowly (updating about 100 rows a second)

- Is this the 'correct' way of doing these updates? Should we be using `Blob` objects? How do we do that to do these updates and new data inserts?
- Is there any reason this might be running slowly?

Comment: BLOBs are stored separately from the regular row data. So they always end up in a different disk page. If you have a spinning hard drive (as opposed to SSDs) and no RAID or huge cache, 100 rows a second is probably as good as it gets, independent of the client side.

Comment: Even for in-row storage?

Comment: I've never heard of in-row storage for BLOBs. An Oracle row is restricted to a single disk page, usually 8K. So if your binary data is really small, you could Base64 encode it and store in a VARCHAR column.

Comment: It's a feature that's been in oracle for a while - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/appdev.901/a88879/adl06fa8.htm

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know. My comment doesn't apply to in-row storage. Do you use in-row storage for you BLOB column?

Comment: Provided your system is fast enough on the server side, you might want to have a look at this [discussion](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1205409). The Oracle driver usually opens a temporary LOB and sends the LOB content to the server separate from the prepared statement execution. Furthermore, it secretly disables batching. In this case, the number of messages exchanged between client and server become the bottleneck. Obviously, it can be prevent if the LOBs are smaller than 32K.